# Application crash when having ActionBar and Custom TitleBar at the same time

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I know that the application crash because of the conflicts between my custom titleBar and ActionBar. But what I can't understand is why the ActionBar.newTab().setText(categoryList[0]) doesn't work even I didn't implement the CustomView

Here is my custom titleBar Style:

```
 <resources>
  <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
  </style>

  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
  </style>
 </resources>

 /***
```

The code in my Activity:

```
public class TestingEndlessAdapterFragmentDemo extends Activity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
private TestingEndlessAdapterFragment simple = null;
private TestingEndlessAdapterCustomTaskFragment customTask = null;

private static enum Tabs {
    TAB_FUN, TAB_MOVIE, TAB_STANDUP, TAB_MUSIC;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); 

    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    // titlebar_title.setText("Prefeerences");
    // titlebar_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.titlebar_list);

    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    String[] categoryList = new String[4];

    categoryList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_name);

    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(categoryList[0]).setTabListener(this)
            .setTag(Tabs.TAB_FUN));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(categoryList[1]).setTabListener(this)
            .setTag(Tabs.TAB_MOVIE));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(categoryList[2]).setTabListener(this)
            .setTag(Tabs.TAB_STANDUP));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(categoryList[3]).setTabListener(this)
            .setTag(Tabs.TAB_MUSIC));


}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    onTabSelected(tab, ft);
}

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    switch ((Tabs) tab.getTag()) {
    case TAB_FUN:
        showSimple(ft);
        break;
    case TAB_MOVIE:
        showCustom(ft);
        break;
    case TAB_STANDUP:
        showCustom(ft);
        break;
    case TAB_MUSIC:
        showCustom(ft);
        break;
    }
}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // no-op
}

private void showSimple(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (simple == null) {
        simple = new TestingEndlessAdapterFragment();
    }

    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, simple);
}

private void showCustom(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (customTask == null) {
        customTask = new TestingEndlessAdapterCustomTaskFragment();
    }

    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, customTask);
}
```

}

Everything works fine except the setText()